# Do not play animate when another is playing

Tags: jquery

I created a topbar with jQuery with, when you hover on div animate start playing, then when mouse out, another animate start playing. ok, the problem is, when you hover you'r mouse many times on div, animate will playing several times, it's repeating. i don't want this!

i tried put this on jsfiddle or codepen, both doesn't work!
here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/ai/easings.net/master/vendor/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bar {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -250px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bar').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({ height: '100%' }, 600, 'easeInBounce');
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({ height: '50%' }, 600, 'easeOutCirc');
    });
});
```

Comment: Try it like this -> ***http://jsfiddle.net/VCUre/***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do in cases like this is using the [:animated selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bar').hover(function() {
        if (!$(this).is(':animated')) {
            $(this).animate({ height: '100%' }, 600, 'easeInBounce');
        }
    }, function() {
        if (!$(this).is(':animated')) {
            $(this).animate({ height: '50%' }, 600, 'easeOutCirc');
        }
    });
});
```

This way your animations will only start if your object is not currently being animated.

Comment: I've got 2 error with this, may you please check this code?
error in visual studio: ) expected

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(this).finish().animate()`. This will stop queued animations and make them finish instantly.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way of really handling this well (depending on what you're trying to do with the animation).

First off, you are using jQuery for mouse hover events, which are known to not work 100% accurately.  JavaScript's `mousemove`, `mouseenter', etc. events are just too finicky.

Secondly, you're using jQuery's `animate` function.  These animations are being queued up.  Best case scenario you'll get the animations to suddenly stop and start again.

The only real way of doing this is using CSS's `:hover` to make your elements animate.  You won't run into the weird mouse events (CSS's handling of `:hover` is much better than JavaScript's), nor will you have an animation queue.  That's all handled behind the scenes so you don't need to worry about it.  We'd need a jsFiddle or something to recreate the animation with CSS though.  [A good example](http://easings.net/) of where to look to recreate your animation effect.

Comment: Wow, that's news to me, javascript mouse events being known to not work accurately and all ?

Comment: There's nothing "technically" wrong with JS mouse events, but there are tons of gotchas that aren't apparent until you work with them for a while (having block level elements, event bubbling, etc). If you ever start working with HTML5 drag n' drop, you'll quickly learn their shortcomings.

Comment: first, i have to say, i should write this with jQ. second, i agree and i think i should use click event instead hover. maybe. i dunno.

Thanks for explain.